# How to show the price in proper currency in different country with IAP

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

It means that when people is going to buy something in my game , and I should show them the price of the object first before they click the "buy" button , but in different countries we need use different currency , if the user is in USA , he should see the price is $0.99 , and in another country I should show them their local currency with the price , so how can I do it in code in my project .
 I am sorry , but I am new to IOS , so really hope to get your help , thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Objective C solution for your needs - you can [include Objective C Header into your swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1506363) and use it.

```
- (NSString *) getLocalizedCurrencyString : (NSNumber *) amount :(NSLocale *)priceLocale
{
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setLocale:priceLocale];
    [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [currencyFormatter setAlwaysShowsDecimalSeparator:YES];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSString *localizedCurrency = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:amount];
    return localizedCurrency;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let priceLocale: NSLocale = product.priceLocale as NSLocale
let price: NSString = IAPHelper.sharedInstance().getLocalizedCurrencyString(product.price, priceLocale)
```

where `IAPHelper` is the Objective C class holding IAP code.

Answer (score 2):

Once you get your products from Apple, you can get the `price` in the local currency from the `SKProduct` - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKProduct/price - that you can then display to the user in your purchase interface.

More details (including a code sample with formatting): http://bendodson.com/weblog/2014/12/10/skproduct-localized-price-in-swift/